# How to access localhost:8080 from vscode server?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, localhost, vscode-remote

I have access to the insider's preview of [vscode-server](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2022/07/07/vscode-server). Instead of a text editor like vscode.dev, this one has a terminal tunnel to an actual remote server. I spinned up an ec2 instance get the code-server running. I managed to get to the vs code server and the terminal on my local web browser. So, I tried to develop a `react` app on it. As per usual, you run the `npm run start` command and there will be a link that direct you to `localhost:8080`. However, when I try to access it, there is nothing on it. Is use case supported yet?

Comment: Is the vscode server running on your remote ec2 instance, or on your local machine?

Are you trying to access `localhost:8080` on your local machine, or on the remote instance?

Comment: Well, the ec2 instance run the `code-server` command. I have insider.code.dev on local web browser. How do you access the ec2 server `localhost:8080`?

Comment: The computer running the live server, and the web-browser you use to navigate to `localhost:8080` must be the same machine. Is this what you are doing?

Comment: My understanding is, the ec2 run both the vs code server and the react app server. My local web browser is just tunneling to it. But I do not know how to access the react app, from my local browser.

Comment: When you say 'there is nothing on it', what do you mean? Does the connection fail? Do you get something back, but it's just not what you expect?

'My local web browser is just tunneling to it' - can you explain what you think is happening here in more detail?